# Is the number of iterations in a bubble sorting algorithm equal to (n-1)! for n elements?

Tags: algorithm, bubble-sort

I recently read in a book, that if we're sorting `n` elements in an array, the number of iterations required will be `n*(n-1)*...*1 = 7!`.

But I'm sure that the actual number of comparisons will be (n-1)+(n-2)+...+1 = n(n-1)/2. So are the number of iterations and number of comparisons somehow different? I'm guessing no, since in each iteration the values are compared [`if(m[j]>m[j+1])`]. So am I missing something, or is the book wrong?

The entire code:

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<7-i;j++)
    {
        if(m[j]>m[j+1])
        {
            t=m[j];
            m[j]=m[j+1];
            m[j+1]=t;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is that each time I see bubble sort implementation here on SO it is wrong ... yes it works but does not stop when array is sorted making it EXTREMLY SLOOOW.. see this How to debug my Bubble Sort code for what you are missing. (the end condition in first loop)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, there is some misunderstanding. For any number `n` of elements, there are

```
n!=1*2*...*(n-1)*n
```

different possibilities to arrange them, which are also called permutations. However, this as such is unrelated to any sorting algorithm. The asymptotic runtime complexity of Bubblesort is

```
O(n^2)
```

as you already mentioned, as Bubblesort is a bit little bit more clever than trying out all possibilities. To finally answer the question proper, *no*, Bubblesort does *not* take `(n-1)!` iterations on `n` elements.